# Array key as a part of a file name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In an array, there are pairs key-value like these ones:

```
ranks: [
    {
      r_mil_pvt_e2: 'Private E-2',
      r_mar_seaman_rcr: 'Seaman Recruit',
      [...]
    }
```

The key is basically a name of a file stored in `./static/img/` directory, it only misses the extension, *.png in this case. So, there are files like `r_mil_pvt_e2.png` there.

Is it possible to use keys and process them dynamically with usage of *v-for* as sources of images in the `<img>` tag below?

```
<v-layout row v-for="r in ranks" :key="r.id">
  <v-flex xs2 v-for="n in r" :key="n.id">
    <img :src="/static/img/[[[ key ]]].png" />
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Vue.JS' documentation von `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object):

> you can also use v-for to iterate through the properties of an object

and:

> You can also provide a second argument for the key

The example they provide is as follows:

```
<div v-for="(value, key) in object">
  {{ key }}: {{ value }}
</div>
```

To use such a variable like `value` or `key` in `v-bind` (or using the short-hand syntax `:`), define it like a function returning the final string.

So, for your example, it should work like this:

```
<v-layout row v-for="r in ranks" :key="r.id">
  <v-flex xs2 v-for="(n, nKey) in r" :key="n">
    <img :src="'/static/img/' + nKey + '.png'" />
[...]
```